# Why do corpses come back to water surfaces after sinking at first?

Tags: physical-chemistry, buoyancy, biology

I want to know that why do dead bodies or corpses come back to the water surface after being sunk at first by the use of stones or anything. 
For what I can understand, I think it's due to water entering the dead body and applying its buoyant force on it which brings it up. Am I right?

Comment: When I glanced at this, I briefly thought it said "Why do corpses come back to life".  I've obviously been watching too many zombie movies.

Comment: "It's coming up threes, boys; it's coming up threes, boys - let me go down in the mud where rivers all run dry"

Comment: Related: [Is there a depth at which a human body with lungs full of air will no longer float?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/122126/)

Comment: @userLTK I have seen many things in life. (Yes lol)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The explanation that I heard was that the human body with air in the lungs is less dense than water but with water in lungs such as drowning is more dense than water and sinks. 
The underwater, presumably dead body, still has live gas producing bacteria in the intestines which start to digest undigested food and eventually the dead person's tissues.
When enough gas is produced to lower the bodies density and the dead body floats to the surface! Thanks for asking!

Answer (score 2):

I believe that as the body starts to decompose, the action of bacteria, particularly in the gut, produce gases, which are trapped.  The gases expand the volume of the body, thereby reducing its density and hence leading to buoyancy, which causes the body to float.

Interesting that a question which looks like physics has a biological answer.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer. Actually, our Physics teacher gave this question as homework, so I thought it would be great to post it in physics section :P