# Is there a depth under which the buoyant force is no longer sufficient to bring a diver back to the surface?

Tags: water, fluid-statics, buoyancy, biology

I came across the story of diver Yuri Lipski who died while diving in the Blue Hole.

This made me wonder something and it may be a stupid question but I thought I'd ask:

For a human diver with normal gear i.e. just a bottle of oxygen, is there a depth under which the pressure of the water above exceeds the buoyancy force the diver is subject to, causing him/her to sink to the bottom?

Comment: If the lungs collapse you are no longer buoyant.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a depth at which a human body, with lungs full of air, will no longer float?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/122126/)

Comment: **FYI:** "normal gear" for a recreational diver includes a [Buoyancy Compenstor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buoyancy_compensator_(diving)) (a.k.a., "BC"). It's an inflatable vest, with valves that the diver can use to let air in from their breathing supply, or let air out as needed to maintain neutral buoyancy. **FYI2:** The buoyancy of a wet suit decreases with depth because increasing ambient pressure compresses the gas trapped in the closed-cell foam and changes its density. A diver wearing a heavy wet suit has to fiddle with their BC more often than a "skin diver" has to do.

Comment: **FYI3:** A rec diver's air bottles become increasingly buoyant throughout the dive. A standard "80 cubic foot" dive bottle holds almost three kilograms of air when it's full, so weighs almost three kilos less at the end of a long dive as it did to begin with. That's the other main reason why the diver must adjust their BC during the dive.